# Cannot logout of XRDP session in Xfce4

Tags: xfce, xrdp

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed and have managed to setup XRDP so I can remote desktop to it from Windows.

Everything works except that I cannot logout of a remote session. When I choose logout from the icon in the top right corner, the desktop clears with just the Xfce4 rodent wallpaper displayed; but, the session remains.

I have edited the `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` file to include the `param8=-once` line under the `[xvnc]` title section but this has made no difference.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem. After restarting the xrdp service with:

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```

the problem seems to be solved till the next restart (?)